# Postgresql is not working in production for REST API where custom query is very long in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, postgresql-10

Postgresql used in spring boot application provides 504 Gateway Timeout error. Dev application is working where data is 1/4th of production data, and memory also 25%. In dev each API is working. When I try with prod(4x data of dev) for some API. Application is in cloud.
Working with postgres 9 and now we shifted to 10.5. Then, I am facing the problem.

One way to check is using the same size of data in dev as with prod
This is the problem of one of my colleague

So, I want to know if there is problem with 10.5(official site written minor uograde) or something else

What may be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably the issue is with the queries you're making, not with postgres. Or you can increase timeout time `spring.mvc.async.request-timeout=1200000` maybe smth like this can help you, but again, I think optimizing queries will be a better sollution

Comment: Yeah, sure thing